# Longest Palindromic Substring using expandfromcenter approach

Tags: java, string, algorithm, cp

I am trying to do Leetcode **Longest Palindromic Substring** with expandfromCentre approach, but instead of returning the length in the function as most of the solutions did, I tried returning the string itself. I think it should work... I don't know what's causing the error.

```
class Solution {
    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        int maxLength = 1;
        
        String res = Character.toString(s.charAt(0));
        
        int start=0; int end=0;
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            String s1 = expandFromCentre(s, i, i); // aba            
            String s2 = expandFromCentre(s, i, i+1);  //abba
            
            if(s1.length()>=s2.length()){
                res = s1;
            }
            else{
                res = s2;
            }
        
        }                
        return res;
        
    }
    
    static String expandFromCentre(String s, int left, int right){
        int n = s.length();
        
        while(left>=0 && right<n && s.charAt(left)==s.charAt(right) ){
            left--;
            right++;
        }
   
        return s.substring(left+1, right);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

```
if(s1.length()>=s2.length()){
   res = s1;
}else{
   res = s2;
}
```

Issue is with the above snippet. You assign either of the value to `res` regardless of whether it will give you the *longest palindrome candidate* or not. In other words, you are overwriting `res` each time without having additional checks for it's length since we need to find the *longest*.

**Solution:**

You can do the below to fix it:

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {        
    String res = "";    
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        String s1 = expandFromCentre(s, i, i); // aba            
        String s2 = expandFromCentre(s, i, i+1);  //abba
        
        if(res.length() < s1.length()){
            res = s1;
        }
        
        if(res.length() < s2.length()){
            res = s2;
        }        
    }                
    return res;        
}
```